# Where should be placed the BufferedInputStream - BufferedOutputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

If I have an InputStream that is wrapped by a lot of InputStream, is there a general rule to place that BufferedInputStream so that the performance will be good?

I mean I could use:

```
FileInputStream > BufferedInputStream > ... > DigestInputStream > LimitingInputStream > NotEmptyInputStream

FileInputStream > DigestInputStream > ... > LimitingInputStream > NotEmptyInputStream > BufferedInputStream
```

My intuition tells me it would be better to place it at the end, but am I right?

What can be the performance impacts of such a choice?

Does it make sens in some case to chain multiple BufferedInputStream ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it directly after the FileInputStream.
This will speed up all following Streams.

Comment: I understand that it will help to speedup the reading of a file, but using the BufferedInputStream at the end can't speedup any other chained InputStream?

Comment: I dont think so, bu there might be special situations where there could be an improvement. In most cases I expect a worse performance when Buffered is at end of a long chain. Try to benchmark boith solutions and post the result here. (Hopefully without file cache implications while measuring)

Comment: thanks but I would like exemples scenarios of where it can be helpful or not

Comment: Yes I understand your theroetical question, from a practical view, each additonial nested stream looses performance (method call overhead). The main gain is to overcomee the bytewise file access. Then I doubt that any adding of an BufferedStream helps. I asume the contrary, its makes things worse, except directly after FileinputStream. I am curious about your profiling results. Probly you cannot measure any advantage when adding Buffered Stream at end

Comment: I know but I guess there are very specific cases where it could help. See that kind of related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177045/digestinputstream-compute-the-hash-without-slowdown-when-the-the-consumer-par

Comment: We already use AsyncHttpClient with a NIO framework behind but it is based on InputStream inputs and I don't think it does raise performances by a factor of 100

Comment: i posted results of different nio technics here, the fastest was memory mapped access (on a pc), 3 times faster. on embedded device java.io was fastests.